# Remove inner row separators of a matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I have the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[cell/.style={rectangle,draw=black}, nodes in empty cells]
  \matrix[
  matrix of math nodes,
  row sep =-\pgflinewidth,
  column sep = -\pgflinewidth,
  nodes={anchor=center, minimum width=2cm, cell},
  column 1/.style = {nodes={minimum width=2cm}},
  row 1/.style = {nodes={text height=1.3ex, text depth=0}},
  row 2/.style = {text height=1.3ex, text depth=0},
  row 3/.style = {text height=1.3ex, text depth=0},
  row 4/.style = {text height=1.3ex, text depth=0},
  row 5/.style = {text height=1.3ex, text depth=0},  
  row 6/.style = {text height=1.3ex, text depth=0},
  ] (m)
  { \\
    \\
    \\
    i \mapsto 5 \\
    \\
    \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

It produces this matrix:

[image]

Does anyone know how to remove all the inner row separators (or color them `white` to do not change the height)? I just want to keep the text surrounded by the big rectangle.

**Edit 1:**

I followed the first solution of the first comment (remove `draw` from the `cell` style options and use it for the `\matrix`), and tried to fill it with color by changing to `column 1/.style = {nodes={minimum width=2cm, fill=purple}},`, it shows the follows. However, I would like the background color to fill the entire rectangle.

The reason why I insist using matrix for this, is because this tikz picture will be aligned with other pictures having matrix (6 rows, `height=1.3ex`). I want them to have the same height. That's why I think maybe changing the color of row separators to `white` may be a good solution...

[image]

**Edit 2:**

I think I need to make my need clearer... Here is the code which produces 2 matrixes side by side. The matrix on the left side is a reference matrix; the one on the right side follows the solution of the first comment. I just want to make them to have the same height: one has inner row separates, the other does not have them and is filled by purple.

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[cell/.style={rectangle,draw=black}, nodes in empty cells]
  \matrix[
  matrix of math nodes,
  row sep =-\pgflinewidth,
  column sep = -\pgflinewidth,
  nodes={anchor=center, minimum width=2cm, cell},
  column 1/.style = {nodes={minimum width=1.5cm}},
  row 1/.style = {nodes={text height=1.3ex, text depth=0}},
  row 2/.style = {text height=1.3ex, text depth=0},
  row 3/.style = {text height=1.3ex, text depth=0},
  row 4/.style = {text height=1.3ex, text depth=0},
  row 5/.style = {text height=1.3ex, text depth=0},  
  ] (m)
  { \\ \\ i \mapsto 5 \\ \\ \\ };
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[cell/.style={rectangle}, nodes in empty cells]
  \matrix[
  matrix,
  fill=purple,
  matrix of math nodes,
  row sep =-\pgflinewidth,
  column sep = -\pgflinewidth,
  nodes={anchor=center, minimum width=2cm, cell},
  column 1/.style = {nodes={minimum width=1.5cm}},
  row 1/.style = {nodes={text height=1.3ex, text depth=0}},
  row 2/.style = {text height=1.3ex, text depth=0},
  row 3/.style = {text height=1.3ex, text depth=0},
  row 4/.style = {text height=1.3ex, text depth=0},
  row 5/.style = {text height=1.3ex, text depth=0},  
  ] (m)
  { \\ \\ i \mapsto 5 \\ \\ \\ };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't it just a rectangle with some text inside it, then?

Comment: Yes... Because I will align this picture with other pictures holding matrix, I want to make it a matrix...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove `draw` from the `cell` style options and use it for the `\matrix` (see below); however, using this for this seems like an overkill since a simple `\node` does the same job with much less effort as also shown below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[cell/.style={rectangle}, nodes in empty cells]
  \matrix[
  draw,
  matrix of math nodes,
  row sep =-\pgflinewidth,
  column sep = -\pgflinewidth,
  nodes={anchor=center, minimum width=2cm, cell},
  column 1/.style = {nodes={minimum width=2cm}},
  row 1/.style = {nodes={text height=1.3ex, text depth=0}},
  row 2/.style = {text height=1.3ex, text depth=0},
  row 3/.style = {text height=1.3ex, text depth=0},
  row 4/.style = {text height=1.3ex, text depth=0},
  row 5/.style = {text height=1.3ex, text depth=0},  
  row 6/.style = {text height=1.3ex, text depth=0},
  ] (m)
  { \\
    \\
    \\
    i \mapsto 5 \\
    \\
    \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[cell/.style={rectangle}, nodes in empty cells]
  \node[
  draw,
  text width=2cm,minimum height=3cm,align=center] (m)
  {$i \mapsto 5$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Update:

Kill the `inner sep` for the `\matrix` but keep it for the nodes inside:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix}

\colorlet{mycolor}{gray!10}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{tikzpicture}[cell/.style={rectangle,draw=black}, nodes in empty cells,baseline]
  \matrix[
  matrix of math nodes,
  row sep =-\pgflinewidth,
  column sep = -\pgflinewidth,
  nodes={anchor=center,cell},
  column 1/.style = {nodes={minimum width=1.5cm}},
  row 1/.style = {nodes={text height=1.3ex, text depth=0}},
  row 2/.style = {text height=1.3ex, text depth=0},
  row 3/.style = {text height=1.3ex, text depth=0},
  row 4/.style = {text height=1.3ex, text depth=0},
  row 5/.style = {text height=1.3ex, text depth=0},  
  ] (m)
  { \\ \\ i \mapsto 5 \\ \\ \\ };
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[cell/.style={rectangle,inner sep=0.3333em,draw},nodes in empty cells,baseline]
  \matrix[
  matrix,
  nodes={anchor=center, minimum width=2cm, cell},
  inner sep=0em,
  fill=purple,
  matrix of math nodes,
  row sep =-\pgflinewidth,
  column sep = -\pgflinewidth,
  column 1/.style = {nodes={minimum width=1.5cm}},
  row 1/.style = {nodes={text height=1.3ex, text depth=0}},
  row 2/.style = {text height=1.3ex, text depth=0},
  row 3/.style = {text height=1.3ex, text depth=0},
  row 4/.style = {text height=1.3ex, text depth=0},
  row 5/.style = {text height=1.3ex, text depth=0},  
  ] (m)
  { \\ \\ i \mapsto 5 \\ \\ \\ };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @SoftTimur Again, use `fill=purple` for the `\matrix`, not for the nodes:  `\matrix[
  draw,
  fill=purple,...`

Comment: Thank you... I edited my OP once again, hope my need is clearer now...

Comment: @SoftTimur Please see my updated answer.